# why i failed to download source code of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

just want to know what happened...

why gyp_chromium returned non-zero exit status? what i should do to deal with this issue?

i have tried to run `sync` for the second time, get the same error...

```
    linux_x86: updated to version 9870.
    Updating /home/thinke365/fun/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_linux_x86.tgz
            from https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/nativeclient-

archive2/toolchain/9870/naclsdk_linux_x86.tgz.
    ......................................
    |------------------------------------------------|
    ..................................................
    linux_x86_newlib: updated to version 9870.
    Updating /home/thinke365/fun/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_pnacl_linux_x86.tgz
            from https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/nativeclient-archive2/toolchain/9854/naclsdk_pnacl_linux_x86.tgz.
    .............................................................
    |------------------------------------------------|
    ..................................................
    pnacl_linux_x86: updated to version 9854.
    Updating /home/thinke365/fun/src/native_client/toolchain/.tars/naclsdk_pnacl_translator.tgz
            from https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/nativeclient-archive2/toolchain/9854/naclsdk_pnacl_translator.tgz.
    ...................
    |------------------------------------------------|
    ..................................................
    pnacl_translator: updated to version 9854.

    ________ running '/usr/bin/python src/tools/clang/scripts/update.py --mac-only' in '/home/thinke365/fun'

    ________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/win/setup_cygwin_mount.py --win-only' in '/home/thinke365/fun'

    ________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/util/lastchange.py -o src/build/util/LASTCHANGE' in '/home/thinke365/fun'

    ________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/gyp_chromium' in '/home/thinke365/fun'
    Updating projects from gyp files...
    Package nss was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `nss.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'nss' found
    gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --cflags nss' returned exit status 1. while loading dependencies of /home/thinke365/fun/src/base/base.gyp while loading dependencies of /home/thinke365/fun/src/build/all.gyp while trying to load /home/thinke365/fun/src/build/all.gyp
    Error: Command /usr/bin/python src/build/gyp_chromium returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/thinke365/fun
    thinke365@lab:~/fun$
    thinke365@lab:~/fun$
    thinke365@lab:~/fun$ n
    bash: n: command not found
    thinke365@lab:~/fun$ echo $?
    127
```

Edit 1:

failed to run install-build-deps.sh even after make comment to some packages which cannot be installed to system.

```
Note, selecting 'libjpeg62-dev' instead of 'libjpeg-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libkrb5-dev : Depends: krb5-multidev (= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze6) but it is not going to be installed
 libnspr4-dev : Depends: libnspr4-0d (>= 4.8.6) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libnspr4-0d (<= 4.8.6-1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libnss3-dev : Depends: libnss3-1d (= 3.12.8-1+squeeze5) but it is not going to be installed
 libpcre3-dbg : Depends: libpcre3 (= 8.02-1.1) but 1:8.30-5 is to be installed
 rpm : Depends: libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: librpm1 (>= 4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: librpmbuild1 (>= 4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: librpmio1 (>= 4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: rpm2cpio but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 3):

As outlined on http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code you will need to run build/install-build-deps.sh before you can run gyp

Comment: failed to run the script... /install-build-deps.sh